# how to configure Oauth2 oidc in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, oauth-2.0

i am trying to configure Oauth2 in my angular project for login.
i have configured it by reading documentation but when ever i hit the login 
it gives me **Unauthorized** error and i dont know how to solve it.
my configurations are

**auth config**

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {

// Url of the Identity Provider
issuer: 'my api base URL',

// URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
redirectUri:  window.location.origin + '/worklists',

clientId: 'oAuth2-login',


 responseType: 'code',

 scope: 'open worklists genstate',

};
```

**app component**

```
 private configure() {
 this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
 this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
 this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
 }
```

**app module**

```
OAuthModule.forRoot({
  resourceServer: {
    allowedUrls: ['my api base url'],
    sendAccessToken: true
  }
})
```

**jwt interceptor**

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.idToken = this.authService.getAccessToken() || '';
// cloning original request and set/add new headers
const authReq = req.clone({
  headers: this.idToken
    ? req.headers
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.idToken}`)
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    : req.headers,
  params: req.params
});
console.log(authReq, 'auth req');
return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

**this is my login service**

```
     public login(payload: LoginPayload, rememberMe: boolean = false) {
return this.httpService.post('/oauth/authorize', payload).pipe(
  first(),
  map((resp: LoginResponse) => {
    console.log(resp, 'response')
    return this.sessionService.storeLoginResponse(resp, rememberMe);
     })
   );
 }
```

i think it's the issue with access token or my configuration
can someone help me? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know almost nothing about Angular but I understand SPA security pretty well - and I'd recommend the oidc-client library

The token issuer should not be your API - it should be a separate 'login' url

My posts may help you with a general direction and the separation of concerns:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the following point:

- Did you enable CORS on server side?
- Is your the client oAuth2-login registered on server side?
- Is the used redirectUrl (incl. the used port) registered on server side?

And last point, can you try to write your redirectUrl with the full syntax (without window.location.origin) and try your app again.

Comment: yes cors is enabled and oauth2 registered on server side and redirectURi would be local host i guess. Ok i will try again

Comment: it isn't working as i am getting the same error 
what will be the issuer is it my api base url or something else m missing and what is allowedUrls?

Comment: and btw what is redirect URi? is it the one we redirect the user to when he sign in successfully