# How to configure Oauth2.0 in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oauth-2.0

i am trying to configure Oauth2 in angular with my login service but i cant be able to achieve desired result

here is the link of module [Oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc)

has someone used it?

i cant understand it if someone explain it that would be great 
thanks

Comment: Please, you will need to get more information about your issues. Provide us at least your error and your login service. Without this information, it's really difficult to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202510/how-to-configure-oauth2-oidc-in-angular-8/57209081#57209081 
here is my issue can you look into it 
thanks

Comment: I answered to your post issue. You can delete this duplicate post.